# Error in passing value from datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I have problem regarding passing the selected cell from datagridview to textbox. The problem is when I select the cell in gridview, it shows error at the code that I already **. I already check all the possible error such as spelling, column have in gridview but still cannot detect wheres the error. Please anyone help me. Here is my code:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

            textBoxName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            **textBoxEmplNo.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();**
            **textBoxWorkNo.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();**


        string selectSql = "select icnum, passport, deptno, section from m_employee where workno=@workno";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workno", textBoxWorkNo.Text);

        bool isDataFound = false;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    isDataFound = true;

                    textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                    textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                    textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                    textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());

                    string imgFilePath = @"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\EV\Images\photo\" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + ".jpg";
                    if (File.Exists(imgFilePath))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Display message that No such image found
                        // MessageBox.Show("No Image Found");
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\EV\Images\photo\No-image-found.jpg");
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: please post the actual error details. Also, when you debug your code, what values are showing for `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value` and `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value`

Comment: Are you using the right event?  CellMouseClick occurs when you click on the datagridview, it does not mean that you have anything selected at all.  Maybe you should use SelectionChanged event instead or you need to check that you do have rows selected first.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I'm sure with that event because when the selected cell is click it pass the value to textbox EXCEPT for code that I **.

Comment: @DeanOC This is the error details : **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**

Comment: what is the `Count` of `SelectedRows[0]` and what is the `Count` of `SelectedRows[0].Cells[1]` ?